# How does torch.einsum perform this 4D tensor multiplication?

Tags: python, pytorch, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I have come across a code which uses `torch.einsum` to compute a tensor multiplication. [I am able to understand the workings for lower order tensors](https://rockt.github.io/2018/04/30/einsum), but, not for the 4D tensor as below:

```py
import torch

a = torch.rand((3, 5, 2, 10))
b = torch.rand((3, 4, 2, 10))

c = torch.einsum('nxhd,nyhd->nhxy', [a,b])

print(c.size())

# output: torch.Size([3, 2, 5, 4])
```

I need help regarding:

1. What is the operation that has been performed here (explanation for how the matrices were multiplied/transposed etc.)?
2. Is `torch.einsum` actually beneficial in this scenario?

Comment: I think this involves [_tensor contraction_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction); so will need help understanding with that perspective!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Skip to the tl;dr section if you just want the breakdown of steps involved in an einsum)*

I'll try to explain how `einsum` works step by step for this example but instead of using `torch.einsum`, I'll be using `numpy.einsum` ([documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)), which does exactly the same but I am just, in general, more comfortable with it. Nonetheless, the same steps happen for torch as well.

Let's rewrite the above code in NumPy -

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((3, 5, 2, 10))
b = np.random.random((3, 4, 2, 10))
c = np.einsum('nxhd,nyhd->nhxy', a,b)
c.shape

#(3, 2, 5, 4)
```

---

### Step by step np.einsum

Einsum is composed of 3 steps: `multiply`, `sum` and `transpose`

Let's look at our dimensions. We have a `(3, 5, 2, 10)` and a `(3, 4, 2, 10)` that we need to bring to `(3, 2, 5, 4)` based on `'nxhd,nyhd->nhxy'`

#### 1. Multiply

Let's not worry about the order in which the `n,x,y,h,d` axes is, and just worry about the fact if you want to keep them or remove (reduce) them. Writing them down as a table and see how we can arrange our dimensions -

```
        ## Multiply ##
       n   x   y   h   d
      --------------------
a  ->  3   5       2   10
b  ->  3       4   2   10
c1 ->  3   5   4   2   10
```

To get the broadcasting multiplication between `x` and `y` axis to result in `(x, y)`, we will have to add a new axis at the right places and then multiply.

```
a1 = a[:,:,None,:,:] #(3, 5, 1, 2, 10)
b1 = b[:,None,:,:,:] #(3, 1, 4, 2, 10)

c1 = a1*b1
c1.shape

#(3, 5, 4, 2, 10)  #<-- (n, x, y, h, d)
```

#### 2. Sum / Reduce

Next, we want to reduce the last axis 10. This will get us the dimensions `(n,x,y,h)`.

```
          ## Reduce ##
        n   x   y   h   d
       --------------------
c1  ->  3   5   4   2   10
c2  ->  3   5   4   2
```

This is straightforward. Lets just do `np.sum` over the `axis=-1`

```
c2 = np.sum(c1, axis=-1)
c2.shape

#(3,5,4,2)  #<-- (n, x, y, h)
```

#### 3. Transpose

The last step is rearranging the axis using a transpose. We can use `np.transpose` for this. `np.transpose(0,3,1,2)` basically brings the 3rd axis after the 0th axis and pushes the 1st and 2nd. So, `(n,x,y,h)` becomes `(n,h,x,y)`

```
c3 = c2.transpose(0,3,1,2)
c3.shape

#(3,2,5,4)  #<-- (n, h, x, y)
```

#### 4. Final check

Let's do a final check and see if c3 is the same as the c which was generated from the `np.einsum` -

```
np.allclose(c,c3)

#True
```

---

### TL;DR.

Thus,  we have implemented the `'nxhd , nyhd -> nhxy'` as -

```
input     -> nxhd, nyhd
multiply  -> nxyhd      #broadcasting
sum       -> nxyh       #reduce
transpose -> nhxy
```

---

### Advantage

Advantage of `np.einsum` over the multiple steps taken, is that you can choose the "path" that it takes to do the computation and perform multiple operations with the same function. This can be done by `optimize` paramter, which will optimize the contraction order of an einsum expression.

A non-exhaustive list of these operations, which can be computed by `einsum`, is shown below along with examples:

- Trace of an array, `numpy.trace`.
- Return a diagonal, `numpy.diag`.
- Array axis summations, `numpy.sum`.
- Transpositions and permutations, `numpy.transpose`.
- Matrix multiplication and dot product, `numpy.matmul` `numpy.dot`.
- Vector inner and outer products, `numpy.inner` `numpy.outer`.
- Broadcasting, element-wise and scalar multiplication, `numpy.multiply`.
- Tensor contractions, `numpy.tensordot`.
- Chained array operations, inefficient calculation order, `numpy.einsum_path`.

---

### Benchmarks

```
%%timeit
np.einsum('nxhd,nyhd->nhxy', a,b)
#8.03 µs ± 495 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
np.sum(a[:,:,None,:,:]*b[:,None,:,:,:], axis=-1).transpose(0,3,1,2)
#13.7 µs ± 1.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

It shows that `np.einsum` does the operation faster than individual steps.

Comment: what benefits does `einsum` have over the full fledged method?

Comment: There are a few optimizations that are added, since you can follow multiple steps to arrive to the same output. If you check the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum) you can see that there is a `optimize` parameter as well.

Comment: As per documentation `"Controls if intermediate optimization should occur. No optimization will occur if False and True will default to the ‘greedy’ algorithm. Also accepts an explicit contraction list from the np.einsum_path function."`