# Matrix multiplication between 2d with 3d?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiplication

Here is the two matrixs:
a's shape is (2, 2) and b's shape is (2, 2, 3)
I want to get c whose shape is (2, 3)

**How can I get c using a and b?**

```
a = array([[0.5, 0.5],
           [0.6, 0.4]])

b = array([[[1, 2, 1],
            [1, 3, 1]],

           [[2, 1, 2],
            [3, 1, 3]]])

c = array([[1. , 2.5, 1. ],
           [2.4 , 1.2, 2.4 ]])

# c = [[0.5*1+0.5*1, 0.5*2+0.5*3, 0.5*1+0.5*1],
       [0.6*2+0.4*3, 0.6*1+0.4*1, 0.6*2+0.4*3]]

# [0.5, 0.5] * [[1, 2, 1],
                [1, 3, 1]]
# [0.6, 0.4] * [[2, 1, 2],
                [3, 1, 3]]
```

Comment: `np.einsum` is what you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using einsum

Try `np.einsum` ([documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)). If you want to know more about how `np.einsum` works, then check this [old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66255845/4755954) which breaks down how its working -

```
np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik',a,b)

array([[1. , 2.5, 1. ],
       [2.4, 1. , 2.4]])
```

#### Using broadcasting

The `einsum` above is equivalent to the following `multiply->reduce->transpose`

> Note: `a[:,:,None]` adds an additional axis to matrix `a` such that (2,2) -> (2,2,1). This allows it to be broadcasted in operations with `b` which is of the shape (2,2,3).

```
(a[:,:,None]*b).sum(1)

array([[1. , 2.5, 1. ],
       [2.4, 1. , 2.4]])
```

#### Using Tensordot

Check out tensordot documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html)

```
np.tensordot(a,b, axes=[1,1]).diagonal().T

array([[1. , 2.5, 1. ],
       [2.4, 1. , 2.4]])
```

Comment: It really helps me a lot. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: `tensordot` is a poor choice here since requires to `diagonal` to "throw-away" most of the values.  `np.dot(a,b).diagonal().T` does the same thing.

Comment: Completely agree, it was just for demonstration purposes  for intuition.

Answer (score 1):

The relatively new `matmul` is designed to handle 'batch' operations like this.  The first of 3 dimensions is the batch dimension, so we have to adjust `a` to be 3d.

```
In [156]: a = np.array([[0.5, 0.5],
     ...:            [0.6, 0.4]])
     ...: 
     ...: b = np.array([[[1, 2, 1],
     ...:             [1, 3, 1]],
     ...: 
     ...:            [[2, 1, 2],
     ...:             [3, 1, 3]]])
In [157]: (a[:,None]@b)[:,0]
Out[157]: 
array([[1. , 2.5, 1. ],
       [2.4, 1. , 2.4]])
```

In einsum terms this is

```
np.einsum('ilj,ijk->ik',a[:,None],b)
```

with the added `l` dimension (which is later removed from the result)