How does torch.einsum get this 4D tensor from a 3D tensor and a 2D tensor?
I have trouble in understanding this line of pytorch code when reading the source codes of mamba_ssm.(source code here: https://github.com/state-spaces/mamba/blob/6dbfc4553a98c81e1e93b8fd2d5abf387f5c09ee/mamba_ssm/ops/selective_scan_interface.py#L121).
# Tensor shape
# b: batch_size, d: d_inner, l: sequence_length, n: d_state
# delta: [b,d,l]
# A: [d,n]
...
deltaA = torch.exp(torch.einsum('bdl,dn->bdln', delta, A))
...

The 4D tensor deltaA is calculated from 3D tensor delta and 2D tensor A. I know torch.einsum, but I cannot figure out what are the operations that have been performed to get deltaA (explanation for how the tensors were multiplied/added/transposed etc.)?
I can understand the code below, since it is matrix multiplication.
torch.einsum('bdl,dn->bln',delta,A)

However, I find it still difficult for me to completely understand what exactly happened in the original code. It seems that it relates with tensor outerproduct, but i'm not sure.

deltaA[b, d, l, n] = delta[b, d, l] * A[d, n] for all valid b, d, l, n indices. Second snippet sums over the d axis, giving a 3d tensor.

deltaA is the "diagonal" (in some sense, over a pair of axes) of a 5d "outer product" (in some sense).

Would this be a helpful duplicate to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66255238/how-does-torch-einsum-perform-this-4d-tensor-multiplication

No, that duplicate doesn't help me with my case. I've checked that carefully twice but still be puzzeled with my problem.
